# count each character in column and give a row header for the table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
select (sum(LEN(cable_no) - LEN(REPLACE(cable_no, '1', '')))*2) as "1",(sum(LEN(cable_no) - LEN(REPLACE(cable_no, '2', '')))*2) as "2"
from MASTER_schedule
where CABLE_TYPE ='MO1'
```

The above sql query output the following tale

```
| 1   |   2  | column headers
|792  |  658 | query result
```

but i would like my table to have a row header as shown below

```
           |    1   |    2   |
|Num_count |   792  |   658  |
```

i am using access database

Comment: You mean a new column with "num_count" in it? **select 'num_count', (sum(LEN(cable_no)....**   If Access complains you might have to use **min('num_count')**

Comment: nope above query doesnot work,instead of new column i will say as a row header

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you actually want.

Comment: my table has column cable_no,cable_type, i am counting the characters in the cable_no i.e. 1124551 1=3times, 2= time as so on,which i do using the above query. i would like to have a name in the actual count row something like 'num_count'

Comment: Well, as there are no "row headers" in SQL this is the best you can get, a new column with the string 'num_count' in it (if Access works as any other DBMS). This column is also named 'num_count', if you don't want that you might assign " " as column name (if Access allows that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should add an empty header with "Num_count" as result

```
SELECT 'Num_count' as "", 
       (sum(LEN(cable_no) - LEN(REPLACE(cable_no, '1', '')))*2) as "1",
       (sum(LEN(cable_no) - LEN(REPLACE(cable_no, '2', '')))*2) as "2"
  FROM MASTER_schedule
 WHERE CABLE_TYPE ='MO1'
```

Comment: NOPE IT DOES NOT WORK

Comment: What do you get as a result? "NOPE IT DOES NOT WORK" won't really help you in finding an answer.

Comment: It give the error invalid alias name and when i say as "A" it say insufficient memory

Comment: i am using ms acces database

Comment: You have to use Key words such as `TRANSFORM` and `PIVOT` to accomplish that layout

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished pretty easy within MS Access query builder. You just need to create a [cross tab query](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_uLJK3mT2o). However, your column heading of `Num_count` is somewhat strange. I was expecting it to be something like cable_type which would make the data/information more meaningful. Anyways if you grasp the concept of crosstab query then you can twist the data whichever way you want. :)